# Change Icon color inside the tab MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the tab icon colour of the Tab which is highlighted and keep unchanged for the rest but I am unable to figure it out. I am passing MUI component inside the icon button.

```js
 <Tab
                icon={
                  <Icon
                    color={cinchdark}
                    name={item.icon}
                    size='small'
                  />
                }
                key={item.name}
                label = {
                  <Typography variant='button'>{item.name}          </Typography>
                }
                {...a11yProps(index)}
              />))}
          </Tabs>
```

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

[image]

**HOW IT IS LOOKING RIGHT NOW**

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, the current icon is black and you want to make it green?

Comment: Yes the highlighted should be black and the rest should be green just like the text

Comment: That's the opposite of what I said... But now I understand. Give me a momemnt.

Answer (score 1):

For Icon, you can add color in classname in  component

```
className={classes.icon}
icon: {
    color: '#F48273',
},
```

To change the indicator color either you can use props

```
TabIndicatorProps={{className: classes.tabIndicator}}
```

and add background color in the class or if this is from your theme you can simply add

```
indicatorColor="primary"
textColor="primary"
```

In your Tabs component.

Comment: No the problem is with the icon not with tab indicator or tab text

Comment: if it is an SVG icon then it will be using same color as the text one you want both of them different for selected one?

Comment: I want them to be the same when the text is black icon should be black when text is green icon should be green.

Comment: check if your svg icon have ```fill: currentColor;```

Comment: but just in case it works it will fill currentColor inside the icon. If we notice svg outline color changes

Comment: no, it will change the outline color

Comment: @AbdullahMujahid What? That's the opposite of what you just told me. MUI tabs should already done what you are looking for out-of-the-box. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#icon-tabs

Comment: @MatthewKwong you are telling right and the problem is what that it is not working the default behavior that's why I asked that way.

Comment: @SakshiMahajan I have checked the value of stroke it doesn't matches with the text

Comment: Just check the color of text "Resume" and the color of icon. They are different

Comment: @AbdullahMujahid then you can simply add classname in icon component I have updated in the answer please have a look

Comment: It will apply that color to all of the tabs .

Comment: God damn it, you are referring to the inactive tabs... You assigned a color to `Icon`, i.e. `<Icon color={cinchdark} />`. I'm not sure whether you did that on every single tab, if you did, then obviously the color will be overwritten.

Comment: @MatthewKwong you are telling 100% correct :) but if I remove cinchdark it will pick black :')